# Apache RewriteRule Proxy does not follow redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am trying to configure Apache 2.4 with mod_proxy as a reverse proxy and I'm having a problem with redirects not passed from the origin server to the client.

I have the following configuration in the virtual host configuration:

```
[...]
ProxyPreserveHost On
# ProxyPass  "/" "http://old.domain.tld/"
ProxyPassReverse  "/" "http://old.domain.tld/"
[...]
```

When using the commented-out ProxyPass directive in the virtual host config, everything works fine. Which means a 30x-redirect from the origin server gets correctly rewritten and forwarded to the client.

When configuring the ProxyPass in .htaccess (which I need because this only should happen under certain conditions), the reverse proxy is working fine except that it does not process any redirects to the client.

I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.domain.tld/$1 [P]
```

Now, I always get a 404 - not found in the client, when the origin server sends a 30x-Redirect.

In the proxy server log, I can see the following traces:

```
[...] strip per-dir prefix: /[...]/domain.tld/htdocs/ ->
[...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[...] rewrite '' -> 'http://old.domain.tld/'
[...] escaped URI in per-dir context for proxy, http://old.domain.tld/ -> http://old.domain.tld/
[...] forcing proxy-throughput with http://old.domain.tld/
[...] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://old.domain.tld/ [OK]
```

The client gets the following headers delivered:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 14:04:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Content-Length: 1060
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Proxy-Connection: Keep-alive
```

I don't understand why Apache or mod_rewrite/mod_proxy is not forwarding the correct redirect when configured in .htaccess.

Is there any solution for that? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ProxyPassReverse its spected to handle redirects so origin server wont take the client outside of the proxy.

> This directive lets Apache adjust the URL in the Location,
>   Content-Location and URI headers on HTTP redirect responses. This is
>   essential when Apache is used as a reverse proxy (or gateway) to avoid
>   bypassing the reverse proxy because of HTTP redirects on the backend
>   servers which stay behind the reverse proxy.
>
> Only the HTTP response headers specifically mentioned above will be
>   rewritten. Apache will not rewrite other response headers, nor will it
>   rewrite URL references inside HTML pages. This means that if the
>   proxied content contains absolute URL references, they will bypass the
>   proxy. A third-party module that will look inside the HTML and rewrite
>   URL references is Nick Kew's mod_proxy_html.

Comment: `ProxyPassReverse` is already set, as stated in the question. But this does not explain the 404 response the OP is seeing. If `ProxyPassReverse` was not set then you _could_ see a redirect back to the origin server, thus "breaking" the proxy - but that is not what's happening here.